# Creating test code for an after insert trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I've got some code I've inherited with no test coverage and fairly little knowledge of apex.

```
trigger UserPartnerSharing on User (after insert) {
    List<OpportunityTeamMember> NewOppteam = new List <OpportunityTeamMember>(); //Create List of leadshares that needs to be inserted
    List<OpportunityShare> NewOppShares = new List <OpportunityShare>(); //Create List of leadshares that needs to be inserted
    List<AccountShare> NewAccShares = new List <AccountShare>(); //Create List of Account shares that needs to be inserted
    List<AccountTeamMember> NewAccTeam = new List <AccountTeamMember>(); //Create List of Account shares that needs to be inserted
    List<LeadShare> NewleadShares = new List <LeadShare>(); //Create List of leadshares that needs to be inserted
    Map<id, User> AccUsrMap = new map<id, User>();//maps partner accounts id to the partner user
    Map<String,Territory_map__c> TerMap = new map<String, Territory_map__c>(); // map to territory 
    List<id> PAccList = new List <id>(); //list of partner accounts id
    List<string> TerNames = new list <String>(); //list of all territorities for new users 
for(user usr:Trigger.new){
    if(usr.ContactId !=null){
        AccUsrMap.put(usr.Accountid, usr); //map account id to portal user
        PAccList.add(usr.Accountid); //adds partner accounts to partner account id list
        system.debug('!!! Users ' + AccUsrMap);
    }        
}
if(PAccList.size() > 0){
    for(Territory_Map__c t:[select id, account__c, Territory__c, Access__c FROM Territory_Map__c WHERE Account__c in:PAccList]){
        TerMap.put(t.Territory__c,t); //add territory mapping with partner accounts
        TerNames.add(t.Territory__c); //add territories to list
        system.debug ('!!! ter list' + TerNames);
        system.debug ('!!! termap ' + TerMap); 
    }
    for(Account a:[Select id, BillingCountry, BillingState, VideoRay_Internal_Only__c FROM Account WHERE VideoRay_Internal_Only__c = False AND (BillingCountry in: TerNames OR BillingState in: TerNames)]){
         if(TerMap.containsKey(a.billingcountry)){
            Accountshare as2 = new AccountShare();
            as2.AccountId = a.id;
            as2.UserOrGroupId = AccUsrMap.get(TerMap.get(a.billingcountry).Account__c).id;
            as2.AccountAccessLevel = TerMap.get(a.billingcountry).Access__c;
            as2.CaseAccessLevel = 'None';
            as2.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'None';
            NewAccShares.add(as2);
            AccountTeamMember atm = new AccountTeamMember();
            atm.AccountId = a.id;
            atm.UserId = AccUsrMap.get(TerMap.get(a.billingcountry).Account__c).id;
            atm.TeamMemberRole = 'Team';
            NewAccTeam.add(atm);
        }
        if(TerMap.containsKey(a.billingstate)){
            Accountshare as3 = new AccountShare();
            as3.AccountId = a.id;
            as3.UserOrGroupId = AccUsrMap.get(TerMap.get(a.billingstate).Account__c).id;
            as3.AccountAccessLevel = TerMap.get(a.billingstate).Access__c;
            as3.CaseAccessLevel = 'None';
            as3.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'None';
            NewAccShares.add(as3);
            AccountTeamMember atm = new AccountTeamMember();
            atm.AccountId = a.id;
            atm.UserId = AccUsrMap.get(TerMap.get(a.billingstate).Account__c).id;
            atm.TeamMemberRole = 'Team';
            NewAccTeam.add(atm);
        }
    system.debug('!!!! ' + TerNames +' '+ TerNames);
    }
    For (Opportunity o:[Select id, Dealer__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Dealer__c in:PAccList]){
        if (o.Dealer__c !=null){
            OpportunityShare ops = new OpportunityShare();
            ops.Opportunityid = o.id;
            ops.UserOrGroupId = AccUsrMap.get(o.Dealer__c).id;
            ops.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit';
            NewOppShares.add(ops);
            OpportunityTeamMember opt = new OpportunityTeamMember();
            opt.Opportunityid = o.id;
            opt.UserId = AccUsrMap.get(o.Dealer__c).id;
            opt.TeamMemberRole = 'Dealer Representative';
            NewOppteam.add(opt);
        }
    }
    For (Lead l:[Select id, Dealer__c FROM Lead WHERE Dealer__c in:PAccList]){
        if (l.Dealer__c !=null){
            LeadShare ls = new LeadShare();
            ls.Leadid = l.id;
            ls.UserOrGroupId = AccUsrMap.get(l.Dealer__c).id;
            ls.LeadAccessLevel = 'Edit';
            NewleadShares.add(ls); 
        }
    }   
    for(Lead l:[Select id, Country, State, VideoRay_Internal_Only__c FROM Lead WHERE VideoRay_Internal_Only__c = False AND (Country in: TerNames OR State in: TerNames)]){
         if(TerMap.containsKey(l.country)){
            Leadshare ls = new LeadShare();
            ls.Leadid = l.id;
            ls.UserOrGroupId = AccUsrMap.get(TerMap.get(l.Country).Account__c).id;
            ls.LeadAccessLevel = TerMap.get(l.Country).Access__c;
            NewleadShares.add(ls);
         }
            if(TerMap.containsKey(l.State)){
            Leadshare ls2 = new LeadShare();
            ls2.Leadid = l.id;
            ls2.UserOrGroupId = AccUsrMap.get(TerMap.get(l.State).Account__c).id;
            ls2.LeadAccessLevel = TerMap.get(l.State).Access__c;
            NewleadShares.add(ls2);
        }
    }
}
if(NewLeadShares.size() > 0){
    database.SaveResult[] NewLeadSharesinsertresult = Database.insert(NewLeadShares, false);
}
if(NewAccShares.size() > 0){
    database.SaveResult[] NewAccTeaminsertresult = Database.insert(NewAccTeam, false);
    database.SaveResult[] NewAccSharesinsertresult = Database.insert(NewAccShares, false);
}
if(NewOppShares.size() > 0){
    database.SaveResult[] NewOppTeaminsertresult = Database.insert(NewOppTeam, false);
    database.SaveResult[] NewOppSharesinsertresult = Database.insert(NewOppShares, false);
}
        system.debug('!!!! Ter ' + TerNames +' ' +TerNames);
        system.debug('!!!!! Lead Share ' + NewLeadShares);
        system.debug('!!!!! Opp Share '+ NewOppShares + ' - ' + NewOppTeam);
        system.debug('Acc Shares' + NewAccShares + ' !! ' + NewAccTeam);
}
```

I've written a short test case shown below and am only getting coverage on the first lines of the trigger. I'm not sure how to ensure the for loop gets hit, and I can't adjust the values of the variables in the conditionals since they aren't part of this class. Anyone have any ideas?

```
isTest public with sharing class UserPartnerSharingTest {
    public static testMethod void testSaas_UserPartnerSharingViaDML() {
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
    User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='testu@testorg.com', ContactId = null);
     insert u;
}
```

Comment: At first glance, I can see that all your logic in the trigger depends on inserted 'User's' ContactId not being null. So is there any particular reason you are inserting a User with a null ContactId in your test class?

Comment: Oops, yeah, that might cause some problems. I did fix it though, and the test coverage didn't improve. I tried changing the if statement to == null as well so see if it was an issue with assigning the contact, but still no improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You're relying on a lot of data already being in the database to make this trigger do anything.

How about taking a different, test-driven approach:

Break out pieces of testable functionality here, e.g.:

- Get Territory Map
- Update Account Information
- Update Opportunity Information
- Update Lead Information

Create an Apex class.  Put each of these pieces of functionality into a separate method.  Accept parameters that are relevant to the function.

Then you should be able to test each piece of functionality on its own.

If you pull out *all* logic into a separate class, it becomes even easier to test.

At worst, I would write the trigger to look something closer to this, and then test the individual pieces:

```
trigger UserPartnerSharing on User (after insert) {
  UserPartnerSharingInsertTriggerHandler handler = new UserPartnerSharingInsertTriggerHandler();
  for(user usr : Trigger.new){
    if(usr.ContactId !=null){
        AccUsrMap.put(usr.Accountid, usr); //map account id to portal user
        system.debug('!!! Users ' + AccUsrMap);
    }
  }
  PAccList = AccUsrMap.keys();

  if (!PAccList.empty()) {
    TerMap = handler.getTerritoryMap(PAccList);
    NewAccts = handler.getNewAccounts(PAccList, TerMap);

   ... etc...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, you are setting up a user in the test method with ContactId = null.

Looking at the code you have a check as it loops through the user on that contactId.  Yours will be null and not go into that chunk.  Therefore your PaccList is empty and the next bit of code won't run.

Usually the contact Id gets filled in when testing a community/portal user as here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009266IAA

Comment: ....and at second glance, you're relying on AccountId... which you're also not setting.  And values in Territory_Map__c and Opportunity, and Accounts, Lead, etc., etc., etc.